# Azure Pipelines - Same hosted agent across stages

Tags: azure-pipelines

How can I have the same hosted agent across multiple stages? For example. Build the solution in one stage, then run tests against those build files in another stage. Without publishing the build files to artifacts.

Comment: I guess you are talking about Microsoft Hosted agent?

Comment: Hey. Yes I am. Not sure if it's possible. Currently I run everything that needs the same agent as separate tasks. But would really like to know how to run stages and jobs on the same hosted agents. So I can have Build, Test, Release as stages, but use the same agent's workspace and files from the build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible on Microsoft hosted agent. Each job will run on a fresh virtual machine which will be discarded after one use.

You will have to publish the build files as artifacts using **publish build artifacts** task. And use **download build artifacts** task to download the build files in other stages/jobs.

If you donot want to use publish and download artifacts task. You will need to create [self-your hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops). It is workable on self-hosted agent.

Comment: Thanks. I thought so. And yes I have been publishing the build items to get around this, or running jobs in parallel and re-building the project in the new stage and job.